# Using CodeMirror. "Cannot set property 'modeOption' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

Currently running into an issue with this.

```js
const configDataNode = document.getElementById('config_data');
    const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(
      document.getElementById('config_data_editor'),
      {
        // lineNumbers: true,
        mode: 'javascript',
        // tabSize: 2,
        // indentWithTabs: true,
        // value: JSON.stringify(gon.config.initialData, 2, 2),
      },
    );
    editor.on('change', changeObject => {
      const {text} = changeObject;
      configDataNode.value = text;
    });
```

Here is my code.

Answer (score 7):

It is happening due to `TextArea` object's value field is `undefined` and thus inside the `CodeMirror` `codemirror.js` library `options.value` is initialising the `doc` variable also undefined, and thus later in source `modeOption` is getting matched with doc child field (if the doc is undefined, how a object key may exists).

```
var textarea_editor = document.getElementById("RichTextArea");

// so explicitly assign value to textarea object.
textarea_editor.value = "";


this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea_editor, {
     tabSize: 4,
     mode: 'text/plain',
     theme: 'default',
     lineNumbers: true,
     styleActiveSelected: true,
     styleActiveLine: true,
     indentWithTabs: true,
     matchBrackets: true,
     highlightMatches: true,
});
```

Hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that `document.getElementById('config_data_editor')` is not a textarea.